# What data should I write to SDL audio callback buffer?

Tags: audio, sdl, sdl-2

I am learning how to generate wave audio by using SDL2.0.

When I init the SDL audio, it asks me to provide a `SDL_AudioFormat` which specifies the audio format, and a callback function which is called when the audio system needs more data.

There are so many audio formats from [SDL Doc](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AudioFormat), but no more information about what actual data I should write to the callback buffer.

I tested these formats:

- float with Sine: (-1,1)
- S8(signed byte) with square wave: [-128, 127]
- U16(unsigned short): [-32768, 32767]

All of them worked.

The question is that I don't know what exactly these audio formats mean.

Can somebody give me some information about it?

Comment: It is the audio bit depth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth, the sound is discretized and you need to range the amplitude of an analog signal at a point, in this case those formats will set how your range (amplitude) is represented. In some sense 8 bit would be a lower resolution than 16 bit, at the cost of space. I wouldn't know if you could talk this way when going from integer to float values.

Comment: @Aram Thanks, it really helps.